# Pass index of apply function to FUN in R or should I do something different?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am currently trying to loop through my data frame called "test" and get the sum of each of the numbers in each column. ex. sum(test$colname1 = 4) would return 1 because of only one 4 occurrence in the first column. I cannot use count because I have 7 specific numbers I want saved (1-7) even if there were 0 occurrences for a number. Count only returns numbers that have occurred and doesn't show 0 values. My plan is to use the apply function to loop through my columns and do the sum of each of the 7 numbers and save the sums into a value and then return those combined values into a data frame where I can do further calculations. Apply requires a function so I decided to do something like this:

```
final_results <- cbind(final_results, apply(test, 2, applyFunction(indexOfApply))

applyFunction <- function(indexofApply) {
temp <- c(sum(indexofApply == 1), sum(indexofApply == 2), 
sum(indexofApply == 3), sum(indexofApply == 4), 
sum(indexofApply == 5), sum(indexofApply == 6), sum(indexofApply == 7))

return(temp)
}
```

I want my result to look something like this:
[image]

My original data frame looks like this 
(column names are confidential)
[image: data frame]

Is there a way to pass the index of the apply function to my own function like I want to do or is there some much easier way to do this? I am new at R and it feels like there should be a better way to do this. Please explain any answers you give so I can learn. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide this in a reproducible manner by providing the output of `dput(DF)` where `DF` is your input data.frame cut down to suitable size. Using images to show the input data is usually not a good idea unless you supplement it with the `dput` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `tabulate` function. 
It will do exactly what your `applyFunction` can do

For example, if I use the following sample:

```
test
   a b c d e
1  1 1 1 7 4
2  6 2 7 7 1
3  1 4 5 3 7
4  3 7 4 7 7
5  2 7 5 1 2
6  1 4 2 1 2
7  1 1 5 2 1
8  3 5 4 2 4
9  6 6 6 3 1
10 4 1 1 5 2
11 6 5 7 1 6
12 1 1 5 4 7
```

Then use `sapply` function, which is same as `apply(x,2,fun)`:

```
result = as.data.frame(sapply(test, tabulate, 7))
```

You can get:

```
result
  a b c d e
1 5 4 2 3 3
2 1 1 1 2 3
3 2 0 0 2 0
4 1 2 2 1 2
5 0 2 4 1 0
6 3 1 1 0 1
7 0 2 2 3 3
```

The disadvantage of `tabulate` is that it can only deal with positive integers. If your category name is not strictly 1 to 7, then you can convert the column into factor and then use `table` to deal with it. Here is my code:

```
result2 <- data.frame(sapply(test, function(x) table(factor(x,levels=1:7))))
```

`result2` is same as `result`, but you can change category names by assigning it to `levels`

Comment: `sapply(test, tabulate, 7)` is same as `sapply(test, function(x) tabulate(x,7))`

Comment: The numbers I am using will always be >=  0 so this is perfect for me. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   # simulating a data set
 df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = T),
             col2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = T),
             col3 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = T))


my_vals = 1:7

 # a shell for the results

df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0,21), ncol = 3))


for (i in 1:length(my_vals))
{ for (j in 1:ncol(df))
   { df2[i,j] <- sum(df[,j] == my_vals [i])}
}

names(df2) <- names(df)

df2


col1 col2 col3
1    2    0    1
2    0    1    0
3    0    2    1
4    0    0    0
5    1    1    3
6    2    2    2
7    1    3    1
```